# X509AttributeCertificateHolder encode and decode

Tags: java, decode, encode, bouncycastle, attributecertificate

Does someone know how to encode/decode a `X509AttributeCertificateHolder`?

I tried the following code (`att` is the created `X509AttributeCertificateHolder`):

```
byte[] arr = att.getEncoded();
X509AttributeCertificateHolder holder = new X509AttributeCertificateHolder(arr);
```

And the problem is: the attributes from `holder` and `att` are not the same.

I used the following simple test:

```
for (int i = 0; i < holder.getAttributes().length; i++) {
    Attribute attr1 = holder.getAttributes()[i];
    Attribute attr2 = att.getAttributes()[i];

    System.out.println("Holder value after decode: " + attr1.getAttrValues());
    System.out.println("Holder value before encode: " + attr2.getAttrValues());
}
```

And the result of the test is:

> Holder value after decode:
>   [[[1][6]#69643a2f2f444155313233343536373839]]
>
> Holder value before encode: [Name: id://DAU123456789 - Auth: N/A]

That's the structure in base64:

```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```

Comment: Could you provide the attribute certificate in base64?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the base64 to it? Because I can't reproduce the same situation here with the info provided.

Comment: I can save the attribute certificate in MySQL into base64 format. Here's a code snippet from encoding and decoding of the attribute certificate.
```java
myDatabase.inserting(acSerial,pkcSerial,Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(att.getEncoded()));
// Convert to AC object
                    byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(b_encoded);
                    certificateHolder = new X509AttributeCertificateHolder(data);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code (and all relevant information) to it. That's preferable and much better than posting it in the comments.

Comment: Here is a link to the project https://github.com/Blackjack92/PMIPrototype/tree/master/PMIExample/src/main/java

Here's the link to the base64 value
https://github.com/Blackjack92/PMIPrototype/blob/master/PMIExample/src/main/java/base64value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check what's going on, I've used your code and did the following:

```
Attribute attr1 = holder.getAttributes()[i];
Attribute attr2 = att.getAttributes()[i];

ASN1Set values1 = attr1.getAttrValues();
System.out.println(values1.getObjectAt(0).getClass());
ASN1Set values2 = attr2.getAttrValues();
System.out.println(values2.getObjectAt(0).getClass());
```

The output is:

> class org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLSequence
>   class org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.RoleSyntax

So, before the encoding (in `att` variable), the attribute value is a `RoleSyntax`. And if you take a look at its `toString()` method, it prints the values in the format `Name: [value] - Auth: [value]`.

But after the encoding (in `holder` variable), for some reason, BouncyCastle loses this information and the attribute value becomes just a `DLSequence`.

To fix this, you need to use this sequence to create a `RoleSyntax` object:

```
Attribute attr1 = holder.getAttributes()[i];

ASN1Set values1 = attr1.getAttrValues();

RoleSyntax rl = RoleSyntax.getInstance(attr1.getAttrValues().getObjectAt(0));
System.out.println(rl);
```

The output will be:

> Name: id://DAU123456789 - Auth: N/A

Comment: very good answer! i think it is a bug in bouncycastle because when encoding/decoding i expect the same object values as before

Comment: Thank you very much Hugo for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help. If you found this answer useful and it solved your problem, you can upvote and/or accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: It is possible to add theRoleSyntax object, especially the attributes to the holder object? The reason is I want to save the holder object with the correct printed attributes?

Comment: Maybe, if you manually rebuild the whole structure, or rewrite bouncycastle's code (not sure if it's worth, though)